# Javascript scrollIntoView is not working with the update panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an update panel in which there is a grid view. In the gridview there are many links. And I have an update progress to indicate that the page is loading on click of any of these links in the gridview. Some times the data in the gridview is so huge that the i have to scroll till bottom and if i click on a link from the bottom, i'll not be able to see the update progress as it is being shown on the top of the page. So tried to work with javascript scroll into view method. But it is not working. Could any one please suggest an alternative for this or any idea to fix the problem.

```
<div onload='dynamicScrollIntoView()'>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="progress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updMain">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <img id="imgPleaseWait" src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl ("~/Common/Images/progressIndicator.gif")%>'
            alt="Please wait..." />
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</div>
```

Below is the javascript used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dynamicScrollIntoView() {
    debugger;
    var updProgress = document.getElementById('<%= progress.ClientID %>');
    if (updProgress != null && updProgress != undefined) {
        updProgress.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Page property

```
 MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="True"
```

Comment: i think this has a different purpose altogether. My purpose is to make the update progress at a viewable position on click of anywhere in the screen.

Comment: That true, once I've seen hidden fields on page, like xcoordpos and ycoordpos, used by MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback. You can use them to initiate absolute position of your update panel.

Comment: could you please state an example...sorry...i put the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback= "true"...and checked the view source...didnt find the co-ordinates..

Comment: Here, take a [look](http://dotnet.nuvvo.com/lesson/11380-maintaining-scroll-positions-during-postbacks) there would be something similiar.